# How to determine the distance from the center of a circle to slice in order for the slice to be a specific length?

Tags: geometry

[image: Slice ?]

I have a circle. I know the `r` is 22.5 mm. I need to slice off the side at a point where the slice is 25 mm long. I need to know, starting from the center point how far the center of that slice will be. How would I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine half of the 25 length being the leg of a right triangle. The radius is the hypotenuse and the value you are looking for is another leg of the right triangle.  Then just use the Pythagorean Theorem.

In this case $$12.5^2+x^2=22.5^2$$

Generally:$${\text{(Half of vertical length)}^2}+\text{(Distance from center)}^2=r^2$$

Comment: Oh. That seams so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Picture remade Ok?